# Joining Two Working Formula's

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following working formula

Located in K2 =IF(INDEX(Details!B18:B81,MATCH(C2,C2,0))<>C2,S30,"0")

So I want it to only use the number in S30 if the date in C2 is not in a range of dates on the Details Page within B18:B81

Now I need to use this formula on the below cells, however, there is an additional check that needs to be done

This working formula is

Located in K3 =IF(AND(C3 < TODAY()+1, J2<>""), K2+S$30, )

So I am wanting the above formula to do what it does if the date in C3 is not in the range on the Details Page within B18:B81 (The date range is either Sunday's or days closed)

If C3 is in the range I want it to add Zero instead of the number from S30

The attached image gives you the cells referenced and for this formula, S30 is equal to 2

[image]

Comment: So this is weird, this formula works, however, only for the first date in the index/match range: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(INDEX(Details!$A$18:$B$81,MATCH(C2,C2,0),1)<>C2,C3<TODAY()+1,J2<>""),K2+S$29,K2+0)). If I modify the formula to be like this =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(INDEX(Details!$A$18:$B$81,MATCH(C15,Details!$B$18:$B$81,0))<>C15, C16<TODAY()+1, J15<>""), K15+S$29, K15+0)) it works for the second date, however, if I drag it down all I get is #N/A with the error being Error
Did not find value '43570' in MATCH evaluation. Thoughts / Suggestions?

Comment: Tried this formula; =(IF(AND(LOOKUP(C2,Details!$B$18:$B$81)<>C2,C3<TODAY()+1,J2<>""),K2+S$29,K2+0)) and get the same error, Error
Did not find value '43556' in LOOKUP evaluation.

Comment: OK with this formula; =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(INDEX(Details!$A$18:$B$81,MATCH(C15,Details!$B$18:$B$81,0))<>C15, C16<TODAY()+1, J15<>""), K15+S$29, K15+0)) I have figured out that I get the #N/A when the reference date (aka C2) in the formula is not listed in the Date Range searched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Ended up using the following formula (after creating an Open/Closed Status column)

=IF(AND(C2="Open",D3""),L2+T$29, IF(AND(C2="Closed",D3""),L2+0,""))